# Can I download Solaris packages directly from OpenCSW?

Tags: solaris

With Linux Debian and RPM package repositories, I can easily download packages via HTTP using a browser.

Is there a way I can do this for Solaris [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/) packages?

I don't have administrator privileges on our Solaris machine and want to try and "extract" the binaries from the packages. The package I want (curl) already has most of its dependencies installed.

[This](http://www.opencsw.org/community/questions/92/installing-without-direct-internet-access) was the closest question I found to mine, and the answer involved using pkgutil. We don't even have pkgutil installed. Another solution I've read involved using a VM and then transferring the binaries, and I actually considered that but the machine is Sparc-based.

Answer (score 1):

Seconds after asking I find my answer,
http://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/